# Left and right align text while content is centered, aswell as adding a break in text - it just won't work

Tags: html, css, alignment, breakpoints

I would like to solve this code mystery which I cannot figure out.

I have a page where I need two columns with a "list" under each H3, okay that part I got figured out.

Next I want the H3's to be where they are but the paragraph text under each H3 should be aligned left on the left and right on the right while still being centered on the screen so to speak. Is this possible?

I've been messing around with aligning in different ways, playing around with margins etc but I can't get it to work!

Additionally, on two of the lefthandside lines I have additional text and I want to use a breakpoint in the text, as in having the 2nd part of the line on a new line. **br** just won't work as the rightside looks all wrong as you can see in my example JSFiddle code below... Any suggestions?

Sorry if I'm being unclear, I find it quite hard to explain so bear with me! :)

Thanks.

The HTML:

```
<div class="border">

<h3 class="solo">H3<span>Rightside</span></h3>

    <p class="text">How do I Leftalign under h3<span>How do I rightalign this under the headline?</span>
    </p>
    <p class="text">Text is now centered<span>T </span>
    </p>
    <p class="text">Text on first line <i>Text on 2nd line</i><span>Text is now</span>
    </p>
    <p class="text">Text on first line <i>Text on 2nd line</i>  <span>Centered</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    margin:10px;
}
.solo {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.solo span {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
.text {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    text-align: center;
}
.text:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: black;
}
.text span {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

JSFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/x6jkjh9q/

Comment: See what you asking for is again same as making text to center. Or do you want the whole left column to left and right column right and then text to be centered? Because if you center text below "H3" that means you don't want it left. **Be clear what you want**.

Comment: @divy3993 http://oi61.tinypic.com/2it0j5v.jpg
Is that clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was busy trying to solve you issue locally.
I hope I am up to the mark.

I modified your code.
HTML I used is

```
<div class="border">

<h3 class="solo">
    <span class="left">H3</span>
    <span class="right">Rightside</span>
</h3>

<p class="text">
    <span class="left-text">How do I Leftalign under h3</span>
    <span class="right-text">How do I rightalign this under the headline?</span>
</p>

<p class="text">
    <span class="left-text">Text is now centered</span>
    <span class="right-text">T</span>
</p>
<p class="text">
    <span class="left-text">Text on first line<i>Text on 2nd line</i></span>
    <span class="right-text">Text is now</span>
</p>
<p class="text">
    <span class="left-text">Text on first line <br><i>Text on 2nd line</i></span>
    <span class="right-text">Centered</span>
</p>
</div>
```

CSS also modified and some were removed.

```
.border {
border-style: solid;
border-width: thin;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
margin:10px;
}
.solo {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
margin-bottom: 1%;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-right: 3%;
text-align: left;
transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
.text:hover {
color: #fff;
background: black;
}

.left {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

.right {
float: right;
width: 50%;
}

.left-text {
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 48%;
}

.right-text {
display: inline-block;
text-align: right;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This... This right here is EXACTLY how I imagined it! You sir, you made my day. I can't thank you enough. Simply amazing. Thank you so much @razorranjan!!
 Would you say this code above is responsive on mobiles and tablets aswell?

Comment: Incredible, mate. Can't wrap my mind around that you figured it out.

Comment: yes its responsive as well. i checked it on 320px with. and on full resolution too. please check once again for its responsiveness in other resolutions too.

Comment: you may upvote my answer if you can do that. @Advokaten

Comment: You're my hero man! Thank you so very much yet again! I did upvote you but I got a message which states I have to earn 15 reputation points or something, if that's bad then I'm sorry...

Comment: nah its okay buddy that's why i said "only if its possible". u will earn points if you participate in answering to others difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you should use `text-align: left/right;`. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6jkjh9q/1/)

**Edit**

You can either add *wrapper* element with smaller width than the container -[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6jkjh9q/5/)-, or use `padding/margin`.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction my man! I just want each side to be centered under each H3, IF that is possible? Thank you so much for your quick response! (not text-align center)

Comment: @Advokaten well, they were centered in your first fiddle.

Comment: Your edits fixed some of what I want to accomplish, I added a bit of margin to show how I want it to look but it's not quiiiteee there just yet. Do you see where I'm going with this or would it be impossible?

http://jsfiddle.net/x6jkjh9q/4/

I also noticed that it breaks when resizing the window which is not the way I want it to act...

Comment: Actually, I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want text on the left to be text-aligned: left, just as you posted, but what I want is the entire text area to be centered under my h3.

Comment: If you can visualize it, then it can be done. Try making an image or something that best describes your goal.

Comment: I'm not the best photoshopper or anything but here's a picture of what I want to accomplish... Thank you again Ahmed.

http://oi61.tinypic.com/2it0j5v.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<div class="border">

<h3 class="solo">H3<span>Rightside</span></h3>
<div class="left">
    <p>left text</p>
    <p>left text</p>
    <p>left text</p>
    <p>left text</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <p>right text</p>
    <p>right text</p>
    <p>right text</p>
    <p>right text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left, .right {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}
.left{
    text-align: left;
}

.right{
   text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah basically that's want it to look like but I will need both left and right to be on the same line as I want the hover effect I posted in my jsfiddle code. I would also like all of the content to be centered WHILE maintaining the text on the left with alignment value left and right side with right. Thank you for your amazingly fast response!